# Making html5 audio snippet resonate past hover with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I've got a little piano here. Right now it works, but the note cuts off when the mouse is no longer hovering over the element (understandably). I'm wondering if it is possible to let the notes resonate after the mouse leaves the < li >. Thanks for your help.

[Piano on webpage (sound works)](http://helloemilyfaye.com/Piano/index.html)

[Jsfiddle - I'm not sure why the sound isn't working here.](https://jsfiddle.net/efmz4crg/)

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

             $("#B").hover(function(){
        note_b.play();

        },
    function(){
        note_b.load();
            });

             $("#bFlat").hover(function(){
        note_bFlat.play();

        },
    function(){
        note_bFlat.load();
            });

             $("#A").hover(function(){
        note_a.play();

        },
    function(){
        note_a.load();
            });

             $("#aFlat").hover(function(){
        note_aFlat.play();

        },
    function(){
        note_aFlat.load();
            });

            $("#G").hover(function(){
        note_g.play();

        },
    function(){
        note_g.load();
            });

             $("#fSharp").hover(function(){
        note_fSharp.play();

        },
    function(){
        note_fSharp.load();
            });

             $("#f").hover(function(){
        note_f.play();

        },
    function(){
        note_f.load();
            });

              $("#e").hover(function(){
        note_e.play();

        },
    function(){
        note_e.load();
            });

             $("#eFlat").hover(function(){
        note_eFlat.play();

        },
    function(){
        note_eFlat.load();
            });

             $("#d").hover(function(){
        note_d.play();

        },
    function(){
        note_d.load();
            });

            $("#dFlat").hover(function(){
        note_dFlat.play();

        },
    function(){
        note_dFlat.load();
            });

              $('#C').hover(function(){
        note_c.play();

        },
    function(){
        note_c.load();
            });

            $('#hi_c').hover(function(){
        note_hi_c.play();

        },
    function(){
        note_hi_c.load();
            });



        });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="box_rotate">
    <nav>
        <ul>

        <li id="hi_c" class="hi_c hvr-grow wrap whole">c</li>
        <li id="B" class="B hvr-grow wrap whole"></li>
        <li id="bFlat" class="bFlat hvr-grow wrap flat"></li>
        <li id="A" class="A hvr-grow wrap whole"></li>
        <li id="aFlat" class="aFlat hvr-grow wrap flat"></li>
        <li id="G" class="G hvr-grow wrap whole"></li>
        <li id="fSharp" class="fSharp hvr-grow wrap flat"></li>
        <li id="f" class="F hvr-grow wrap whole"></li>
        <li id="e" class="E hvr-grow wrap whole"></li>
        <li id="eFlat" class="eFlat hvr-grow wrap flat"></li>
        <li id="d" class="D hvr-grow wrap whole"></li>
        <li id="dFlat" class="dFlat hvr-grow wrap flat">c</li>
        <li id= "C" class="C hvr-grow wrap whole">
            <p>c</p></li>


    </ul>
    </nav>


 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-4"></div>





<audio id="note_c">
<source id="C" src="http://helloemilyfaye.com/Tones/c.mp3"       type="audio/mp3"/>
 </audio>

<audio id="note_dFlat">
 <source id="dFlat" src="http://helloemilyfaye.com/Tones/csharp.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
  </audio>

 <audio id="note_d">
 <source id="d" src="http://helloemilyfaye.com/Tones/d.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
  </audio>

 <audio id="note_eFlat">
<source id="eFlat" src="http://helloemilyfaye.com/Tones/eflat.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
</audio>

 <audio id="note_e">
 <source id="e" src="http://helloemilyfaye.com/Tones/e.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
  </audio>

 <audio id="note_f">
 <source id="F" src="http://helloemilyfaye.com/Tones/f.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
  </audio>

 <audio id="note_fSharp">
 <source id="fSharp" src="http://helloemilyfaye.com/Tones/fsharp.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
  </audio>

  <audio id="note_g">
 <source id="G" src="http://helloemilyfaye.com/Tones/g.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
  </audio>

  <audio id="note_aFlat">
 <source id="aFlat" src="http://helloemilyfaye.com/Tones/gsharp.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
  </audio>

 <audio id="note_a">
 <source id="a" src="http://helloemilyfaye.com/Tones/a.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
  </audio>

 <audio id="note_bFlat">
 <source id="bFlat" src="http://helloemilyfaye.com/Tones/bflat.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
  </audio>

    <audio id="note_b">
 <source id="B" src="http://helloemilyfaye.com/Tones/b.mp3"/>
  </audio>

 <audio id="note_hi_c">
 <source id="hiC" src="http://helloemilyfaye.com/Tones/hi_c.mp3"/>
  </audio>
```

**CSS**

```
    body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    font-size: 15px;
}



/*--------------------LISTS---------------------*/


li{
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
    color: white;

}
.flat{
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.whole{
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
}



/*--------------------NOTES---------------------*/


.C{
    background-color: #00a200;
    Opacity: .5;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70%;
    z-index:0;
    margin-bottom: -27px;


}
.C:hover{
    opacity: .2;

}

.dFlat{
    background-color: #409cac;
    Opacity: 1;
    height: 40px;
    width: 50%;
    z-index:9;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: -35px;


}
.dFlat:hover{
    opacity: .9;

}

.D{
    background-color: #0000ff;
    Opacity: .5;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70%;
    margin-bottom: -37px


}
.D:hover{
    opacity: .5;

}

.eFlat{
    background-color: #ad82ff;
    Opacity: 1;
    height: 40px;
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: -40px;
    z-index:9;
    position: relative;

}
.eFlat:hover{
    opacity: .9;

}

.E{
    background-color: #c488c2;
    Opacity: .5;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70%;
    margin-bottom: -44px;
}

.E:hover{
    opacity: .5;

}

.F{
    background-color: red;
    Opacity: .5;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70%;
    margin-bottom: -10px;

}
.F:hover{
    opacity: .5;

}

.fSharp{
    background-color: #e62800;
    Opacity: 1;
    height: 40px;
    width: 50%;
    z-index:9;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: -30px;

}
.fSharp:hover{
    opacity: .9;

}
.G{
    background-color: #fd4f0d;
    Opacity: .5;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70%;
    margin-bottom: -37px

}
.G:hover{
    opacity: .2;

}

.aFlat{
    background-color: #ff8000;
    Opacity: 1;
    height: 40px;
    width: 50%;
    z-index:9;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: -40px;

}
.aFlat:hover{
    opacity: .5;

}
.A{
    background-color: #e89804;
    Opacity: .5;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70%;
    margin-bottom: -45px;

}
.A:hover{
    opacity: .2;

}
.bFlat{
    background-color: #ffff00;
    Opacity: 1;
    height: 40px;
    width: 50%;
    z-index:9;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: -45px;

}
.bFlat:hover{
    opacity: .5;

}
.B{
    background-color: #c7de21;
    Opacity: .5;
   height: 70px;
    width: 70%;
    margin-bottom: -54px;

}
.B:hover{
    opacity: .2;
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}

.hi_c{
    background-color: #00a200;
    Opacity: .5;
   height: 70px;
    width: 70%;
    margin-bottom: -39px;
    margin-top: -50px;

}
.hi_c:hover{
    opacity: .2;

}




/*--------------------DIVs---------------------*/

div.static {
    position: static;

} 

/*--------------------HOVER---------------------*/


.hvr-grow {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transform: translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition-duration: 0.1s;
    transition-property: transform;
}

.hvr-grow:hover,
.hvr-grow:focus,
.hvr-grow:active {
    transform: scale(.95);
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*--------------------TINT---------------------*/


.tint {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.2) 3px 5px 5px;
}

.notint {
    opacity: 1.0;


}


.hvr-fade {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-property: #59fdd8, #f01010;
    transition-property: color, background-color;
}

.hvr-fade:hover, .hvr-fade:focus, .hvr-fade:active {
  background-color: #2098d1;
  color: white;
}

div{

    font-size: 2em;
}

.box{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: grey;
}

.box_rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);  /* Chrome, Safari 3.1+ */
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);  /* Firefox 3.5-15 */
      -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);  /* IE 9 */
        -o-transform: rotate(90deg);  /* Opera 10.50-12.00 */
         transform: rotate(90deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.50+ */
}
.box_transition {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Chrome 1-25, Safari 3.2+ */
     -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Firefox 4-15 */
       -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Opera 10.50–12.00 */
          transition: all 0.3s ease-out;  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.50+ */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hover-out event you are assigning to the notes explicitly tells the audio to reload, which stops it from playing.

```
 $("#dFlat").hover(function(){
        note_dFlat.play(); //hover in handler

        },
    function(){
        note_dFlat.load(); //hover out handler
            });
```

Changing the out handler to do nothing should allow the audio tag to finish it's play cycle (you may need to revisit the hover-in handler to re-start the audio):

```
$("#dFlat").hover(function(){
            note_dFlat.play(); //hover in handler

            },
        function(){
           return; //hover out handler
                });
```